# Is it valid for function parameter's names to be the same as the variables used in the call to the function?

Tags: c++, function, variables

Say I have a function:

```
int add(int num1, int num2) { 
    num1 += num2;
    return num1;
}
```

is it programatically correct to call the function with variable(s) which contain the same name(s) as the function's parameter's names?

example:

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 10;

int result = add(num1, num2)
```

Or is it programatically correct to use different names for the function call's variables/function parameters.

Comment: This is mostly a matter of opinion. Personally, I always try to use consistent naming. This makes searching a large code base easier, easier to see where things are coming and going to.

Comment: The variables used when calling a function and the argument variables themselves have no other relation than the value of one variable is copied into the other variable. Once that copying is done, the two variables are separate and distinct.

Comment: It's more so about validity rather than opinion.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think this is opinion-based. This is just a very simple and basic programming question.

Comment: I often see beginners confusing argument and the parameter. I have even seen ppl write the same function twice just because the parameter has a different name. I cannot decide which one to choose when teaching a beginner, but either of the two options should come with proper explanation that `num1` and `num1` are not the same object

Comment: The title has been edited to represent validity.

Comment: Yes, it is valid. Why do you think it might not be? It compiles, doesn't it? (with a sane level of warnings on, not that warnings seem applicable if it weren't allowed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Those variables are in different scopes, therefore it is perfectly valid. See [Name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) and [Scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope):

> Each name that appears in a C++ program is only valid in some possibly
>   discontiguous portion of the source code called its scope.

Comment: @Downvoter did I read the question wrong? What is the problem?

Comment: @PeteKirkham *"is it programatically correct"* reads more like "is it valid" than "should I".

Comment: @PeteKirkham "is it programatically correct" Seems to ask about validity.

Comment: Therefore this answer is on-topic and correct. cc @PeteKirkham ;)